# Angular Module - One per application or feature?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to Angular here.

Conceptually, should a module be one per application? Or should I be creating a new module per feature?

Example: For my login page, would I have a login module; then for my orders page, I"ll have an orders module; and for my users page, a users module, etc. ?

Or would everything be umbrellaed into a single module?

Thanks!

Comment: Think SPA first...then decide on how many pages you want. Usually its one module per page...

Comment: Thanks @deostroll. So to ensure that I understand correctly: In my example above, I would have a login, orders and users module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to decompose an angular app by features and a module per feature approach. It makes the app much modular, easily manageable and extensible easily. But you must carefully plan your modules/features. You can take a look at [hottowel SPA app generator](https://github.com/johnpapa/generator-hottowel)

Comment: Thanks for your input @nmrony. I'm leaning to this approach as well now!

Comment: I have added the link.